# Flutter reversed List View scroll to bottom when new item added

Tags: flutter

Reversed ListView.builder does not scroll to new added item when I'm viewing the bottom of list.

```
messageList.insert(0, newMessage);

setState(() {});

SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   _messageListController.animateTo(
      _messageListController.position.minScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
     curve: Curves.easeOut);
});
```

I also use addPostFrameCallback after adding new item. It just works whenever I view the above items (not at the end of list).

Please help me find out solution for this circumstance. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why reserved ListView.builder does not scroll to bottom when new added item: Because I don't use `ValueKey` for each item.

Solution:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) => MyItem(key: ValueKey(item.id)
)
```

Note: You can use either `ValueKey` or `ObjectKey`. What's difference?

- `ValueKey`: compare value.
- `ObjectKey`: compare address.